# The more organized your code, the more slow your website or programme will run?

Tags: performance

Just wondering that, the more you keep your code organized, like using MVC, or keeping separate files for functions, constants, using external sheets for styles, JS, etc. the more  slow the website becomes, because the value in the code has to follow a longer path, comparatively.
Is it true??

Comment: Yes this is true. <-- that would have been my answer. See why that really doesn't work in a Q&A?

Answer (score 1):

It's true in the sense that your page will take 0.02 seconds instead of 0.01 seconds to process.

Long-term maintainability of code is much more important than raw performance 99% of the time.